# jQuery .each loop with simple math not giving individual results

Tags: jquery, css, math, each

I'm attempting to loop through each `.student-item` div, calculate a bunch of different values from various numbers inside each `.student-item`(the numbers won't need to change), and output new text and/or add/modify css styles with those values.

### Problems

1. Though the `.each` seems to be working—I'm logging messages to the console right after each main part of the loop, and I'm seeing 10 of each, which is the correct number of items—see #2 below.
2. The math is not working(and thus the `.else` loop?). I'm also logging one of the variables, `scoreChangeNum` containing some *simple* math that should show only if one `.hasClass` conditions is met(which should apply to 7 of the `.student-items`'s in this case). You'll also see the `+-8 ytd` text. This text is being calculated in the `scoreChangeNum` variable and appended inside the span. The calculation is wrong(each number should be from ~10 to ~300) and it's being written for each `.student-item`(they should all be different).
3. The css I'm adding to certain elements isn't moving them into place as it should. I'm guessing because the math seems to be off..? The position(and width of some elements) should be determined by the numbers inside different elements.

Does that make sense? Sorry for the run-ons. Would love some tips on what's going wrong here. Let me know if anything is unclear. Thanks!

***EDIT*** (Adding code here.):

*HTML* (But there are 10 of the `.student-item`'s total)

```
<div class="students-list">
  <div class="student-item">
    <a href="#" class="name">Jim Wise</a>
    <div class="score-bar">
      <div class="scores">
        <div class="current-score point">180</div>
        <div class="orig-score-arrow"></div>
        <div class="orig-score">80</div>
        <div class="score-change">+<span class="score-change-amount">nnn</span> ytd</div>
      </div>
      <ul id="markings">
        <li>&nbsp;</li>
        <li>&nbsp;</li>
        <li>&nbsp;</li>
        <li>&nbsp;</li>
        <li>&nbsp;</li>
        <li>&nbsp;</li>
        <li>&nbsp;</li>
        <li>&nbsp;</li>
        <li>&nbsp;</li>
        <li>&nbsp;</li>
        <li>&nbsp;</li>
        <li>&nbsp;</li>
        <li>&nbsp;</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="print-icon"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="student-item">
    <a href="#" class="name">Frank Owens</a>
    <div class="score-bar">
      <div class="scores">
        <div class="current-score point">280</div>
        <div class="orig-score-arrow"></div>
        <div class="orig-score">100</div>
        <div class="score-change">+<span class="score-change-amount">nnn</span> ytd</div>
      </div>
      <ul id="markings">
        <li>&nbsp;</li>
        <li>&nbsp;</li>
        <li>&nbsp;</li>
        <li>&nbsp;</li>
        <li>&nbsp;</li>
        <li>&nbsp;</li>
        <li>&nbsp;</li>
        <li>&nbsp;</li>
        <li>&nbsp;</li>
        <li>&nbsp;</li>
        <li>&nbsp;</li>
        <li>&nbsp;</li>
        <li>&nbsp;</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="print-icon"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

*jQuery*

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var studentItem = '.student-item';

  $(studentItem).each(function(){
    console.log('"each" function - CHECK');

    var currentScoreElement = '.current-score',
        origScoreArrow = '.orig-score-arrow',
        origScoreElement = '.orig-score',
        origScoreNum = parseInt($(origScoreElement).text()),
        origScorePos = parseInt(origScoreNum * .48),
        scoreChangeSpan = '.score-change-amount';

    console.log('initial variables - CHECK');

    if ( $(currentScoreElement).hasClass('point') ) {
      var currentScoreNum = parseInt($(currentScoreElement).text()),
      currentScorePointPos = parseInt(currentScoreNum * .48),
      origScoreArrowWidth = parseInt((currentScorePointPos - origScorePos) * .9),
      scoreChangeNum = parseInt(currentScoreNum - origScoreNum);

      console.log(scoreChangeNum);

      $(currentScoreElement).css({ 'left': currentScorePointPos + 'px' });
      $(origScoreElement).css({ 'left': origScorePos + 'px' });
      $(origScoreArrow).css({ 'left': origScorePos + 'px', 'width': origScoreArrowWidth + 'px' });
      $(scoreChangeSpan).text(scoreChangeNum);
      $(scoreChangeSpan).css({ 'left': parseInt(currentScorePointPos - 12) + 'px'     });

    } else if ( $(currentScoreElement).hasClass('range') ) {
      var currentRangeStart = parseInt($(currentScoreElement).find('.start').text()),
      currentRangeEnd = parseInt($(currentScoreElement).find('.end').text()),
      currentRangeWidth = parseInt(currentRangeEnd - currentRangeStart),
      currentRangeAvg = parseInt((currentRangeStart + currentRangeEnd) / 2);
      origScoreArrowWidth = parseInt(currentRangeAvg - origScorePos),
      scoreChangeNum = parseInt(currentScoreNum - origScoreNum);

      $(currentScoreElement).css({ 'left': currentRangeStart + 'px', 'width': currentRangeWidth + 'px' });
      $(origScoreElement).css({ 'left': origScorePos + 'px' });
      $(origScoreArrow).css({ 'left': origScorePos + 'px', 'width': origScoreArrowWidth + 'px' });
      $(scoreChangeSpan).text(scoreChangeNum);
      $(scoreChangeSpan).css({ 'left': parseInt(currentRangeAvg - 12) + 'px' });
    }

  });

});
```

Comment: You should be able to add/embed your code here as a working version, saves others having to leave the page :-)  Not sure but you have this calucaltion within the parseInt `parseInt(currentScoreNum * .48)` could you try it like `parseInt(currentScoreNum) * .48`

Comment: The project just contains a lot of code, so I chose brevity over leaving the page. I tried `parseInt(currentScoreNum) * .48` instead of `parseInt(currentScoreNum * .48)` and it didn't seem to change the math.

Comment: if you log out all teh values as they are done for instance for the `origScoreNum` value i get the value 8.01004202408032e+27??

Comment: Yea, I'm getting that for `origScoreNum` too. You can see in the html that the math shouldn't get near to that high—none of the numbers I'm calculating are above ~600, and any multiplication is to a fraction (eg .48, etc). That's the whole problem, really.

Comment: when i output $(origScoreElement).text() i get 8010042024080320290510420550 si that correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is `$(origScoreElement)` is selecting all div.orig-score elements on the page, and .text() is returning the text of the first. You need to select only the div.orig-score that is a child of the current div.student-item, using `$(origScoreElement, this)`.

Comment: Since the variable `origScoreElement` is set to the string ".orig-score", then shouldn't `$(origScoreElement)` be the same as `$(".orig-score")`? And I thought because it was inside the `.each` loop that it would only grab the one `.orig-score` in each `.student-item`. Should I replace any uses of variables like this with the `$(**variable**, this)` syntax then?

Comment: @dmoz What makes you think that being inside a `.each()` loop restricts the selector to searching inside that element?

Comment: $(origScoreElement) will select all matching elements on the page regardless where the code appears. The scoped selector $(origScoreElement, this) will only select elements within the specified scope (children of this).

Comment: @dmoz If you want to search only in the current loop element, you need to say it explicitly, either `$(this).find(origScoreElement)` or `$(origScoreElement, this)`

Comment: I guess I thought that's what the `.else` loop did—looped through each element performing the tasks inside the loop until it has no more elements to loop through. Did you have a suggestion for an answer?

Comment: The loop does not in any way constrain your scope to the current element. It just gives you a reference to the current element (this). Replace all selectors you want limited with the scoped syntax and you should get the right elements.